# Native Persistence and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is really the advantage of going with provider such as hibernate if we can accomplish the ORM with native java support with javax.persistence.*

The book java persistence with hibernate said that,

```
Hibernate EntityManager is a wrapper around Hibernate Core that provides the
JPA programming interfaces, supports the JPA entity instance lifecycle, and allows
you to write queries with the standardized Java Persistence query language.
```

Here the name Hibernate EntityManager confuse me. Does EntityManager belongs to hibernate?

Also Below is how to persist a domain object throgh java persistence,

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("helloworld");
// First unit of work
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
```

Below is the persistence.xml file used with,

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="helloworld">
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile"
value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So here again persistent unit declares the hibernate configuration file. So what is the object  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("helloworld"); is actually retrun here?

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Which object does createEntityManager() method holds?

Answer (score 2):

JPA (Java Persistence Api) is a *specification* (I think the JRE only has interfaces) that can be implemented by a number of providers.

As such, Hibernate (for example) makes available classes implementing JPA specification using the hibernate core.

The reason of using JPA over Hibernate is that Hibernate is fully propietary; they can change their API as they wish, and if you use Hibernate API you are forced to use Hibernate as your ORM. JPA is standard, any ORM provider may chose to meet the JPA specification and provide its services through it (f.e. EclipseLink).

By using JPA, you can swith your ORM easily, in case you find some that fits you better (performance, bugs fixed, etc.) than the one you are currently using. You cannot do that as easily if you are using Hibernate directly.

Comment: so the hibernate specific objects much implement EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager interfaces right?

Comment: The objects of Hibernate that implement JPA do. Most probably, internally these objects will delegate the logic to the Hibernate-only classes (like `Session`, which is not part of the JPA specification).